# How to optimize a MySQL JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this MySQL query that I want to optimize:

```
SELECT r.WarehouseLocation,sum(sir.qty) 
FROM repairableissue as r 
INNER JOIN SIR ON r.sirno=sir.sirno 
    AND r.region=sir.region 
    AND r.ItemName=sir.Itemdesc 
    AND r.SerialNo=sir.Serialno
WHERE r.status='Pending' 
GROUP BY r.warehouseLocation
```

How do I optimize this query?  I read about optimization and found out that indexes might help but still could not achieve the desired performance.

Which index should be used and which should be removed?

Below is the explain of query:
[image]

**Repairableissue**

```
CREATE TABLE `repairableissue` (
 `Vendor` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `ItemName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `SerialNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `person` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `siteid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `invuser` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Dated` date NOT NULL,
 `Sirno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
 `trackthrough` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `reason` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `ckh` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `WarehouseType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `WarehouseLocation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `I1` (`status`),
 KEY `ind2` (`ItemName`),
 KEY `ind3` (`region`),
 KEY `ind5` (`SerialNo`),
 KEY `ind4` (`Sirno`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=63029 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**sir**

```
CREATE TABLE `sir` (
 `SirNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `SiteId` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `Vendor` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
 `Type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `ItemDesc` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `ItemCode` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `SerialNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Unit` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `AssetCode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Qty` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
 `Region` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `Status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Installed',
 `FaultInfo` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'date()',
 `chk` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Phase` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `Category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `Issue_Vendor` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `AssetName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `Ownership` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `Dated` date NOT NULL,
 `PersonName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `Remarks` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `po` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `invuser` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `grnno` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `WarehouseType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `WarehouseLocation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `mainpartserial` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Vendor`,`Type`,`ItemCode`,`ItemDesc`,`SerialNo`,`Ownership`,`SirNo`,`Region`,`WarehouseType`,`WarehouseLocation`,`po`,`Qty`,`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `ind4` (`ItemDesc`),
 KEY `ind6` (`SerialNo`),
 KEY `ind7` (`SerialNo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=228007 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: table structure? can you make `explain <query>`?

Comment: @jcho360 that _is_ the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Please give the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: Question is updated with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: i just accepted some edit and that was removed :) added again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One [multi-column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) index on `r.status` + `r.warehouseLocation`, in that order.

One multi-column index on `sir.sirno` + `sir.region` + `sir.Itemdesc` + `sir.Serialno`, in order of most cardinality to least cardinality, with `sir.qty` tacked on the end.

This assumes the fields are small enough to fit (combined) into an index.

Still, join seeks are unavoidable. The number of records that match `r.status='Pending'` is going to dictate the speed of this query.

Comment: i have created indexes on each but sorry don't know the compound indexes

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan, I updated my answer with MySQL specific terminology and a link. Take a look.

Comment: O my GOD! it did the trick. one question are these index could effect my other queries on these tables. seriously it is owsome

Comment: can you please guide me some resource where i can learn abut technique of using indexes?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan, indexes can negatively impact inserts. Remove any unused indexes.